# itext Editable PDF javascript to enable or visible or show existing page on button click

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext

itext Editable PDF javascript to enable or visible or show existing page. 
I have a Editable PDF Template which have total number of pages 2. Initially I want only one page and on button click I need 2nd page.

I have added Javascript onload of PDF and set action on button click.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
reader.selectPages("1");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
```

- List item
  1) I have Template which have total 2 pages.
  2)Though above code I will get only 1 page as output PDF.
  3)Now I need 2nd page which already in template using javascript on button click.
  4) This below code is only showing how I have added script on button click.

  PdfFormField submit1 = button1.getField();
  submit1.setAction( PdfAction.javaScript("setReadOnly(true,"+isCoSite+");",
  stamper.getWriter()));

Comment: This is only possible with XFA. iText doesn't manipulate XFA forms. It can fill and flatten XFA forms, but it doesn't change JS in an XFA form. If you claim that your requirement is possible using AcroForm technology, please show us a PDF with this behavior. I've never seen such a PDF, which makes me believe you're asking something that is impossible (until someone shows me such a PDF). Or maybe I just don't understand your question, in which case you should edit it and clarify. For instance: your code sample isn't complete and it doesn't correspond with what you're asking. It's confusing.

Comment: I am not sure about this is possible or not. But I have one template which using AcroForm tec.  and In this template , on button click I could able to open existing page which I have made hidden while creating PDF. I have used same code like above but in template how it's opening existing pages on button click that I could not identify.

Comment: How did you "hide" the existing page (you write: "which I have made hidden while creating PDF.") Also: the code you write refers to a method named "setReadOnly", which seems to be a custom JavaScript method. What is this method about? I'll vote to close this question if you don't clarify. Right now, your question isn't clear.

Comment: I am editing my question. After that If you do not found clear query then close this one. Because My question is related code is first three line , Rest two line I have added , just because showing how I have added java script on button click.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You might want to read *12.7.6 Named Pages* in the spec once again... ;) And I remember experimenting with those named pages and instantiating them etc using iText in the old 2.1.x times.

Comment: @mkl I thought this was an Acrobat-only kind of things. I'd like to see it work with all PDF viewers (I don't think it does, but please prove me wrong).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Well, at least that is part of the PDF specification, so a full-blown PDF viewer *should* support page templates. Admittedly, though, there are quite a number of parts of the spec not supported by many PDF viewers

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: As mkl stated, Template pages can be hidden or shown, and Acrobat JavaScript does actually know the template.hidden property. However, Adobe limited it to work only in Acrobat, not in Reader. With Reader XI or newer, it is possible to spawn a Template page, and it is also to delete a spawned page within the same session. However, I am not aware of any other PDF viewer which supports Templates (but my collection of supported objects, methods and properties is incomplete, and there are vendors which have not responded to my request for information…).

Comment: @MaxWyss Functionality that isn't fully supported is often blocked from my memory ;-) I've had too many people say "we've tried this with iText(Sharp) *and it doesn't work.*" I'm sick and tired of people who say ["it doesn't work"](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork) when they're trying to do something that works, but not in the way they expect. Maybe we still have a chance to deprecate page templates in PDF 2.0.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie …and deprecate Page Templates in PDF 2.0 would bring PDF back to PDF 1.0 (or so), wouldn't it? Of course, if you try to do something, you always have to be prepared that something does not work the way you expect. In the majority of the cases, the bug is in your expectation; in some cases, it is actually a bug…

Comment: @MaxWyss PDF 2.0 is an opportunity to clean up the PDF specification and to remove functionality that (1.) doesn't seem to be used by many people, and (2.) is used in ways that aren't ideal. I remember IBM's plea to keep `/PieceInfo` in the spec at the ISO meeting in San Jose, but it got deprecated anyway.